# Timeline items on Glass file structure

Tags: google-glass

I assume that the cards on the timeline are stored locally on Glass - I was wondering if details about where and how they are stored is available.  I see the images are stored in a particular cache folder, but not sure about how they are organized.  Or is this something that Google doesn't want played with at this point?

I was trying to reorganize timeline items (via mirror) into bundles by content-type and forgot about the restrictions via oauth, so I assume a native or root application would be required.

Comment: you can update old timeline items (if you know their ID) to be included into a new bundle that you create, I haven't been able to figure this out yet

Answer (score 0):

The local timeline items are organized by time received.

I think that the timeline items are being hosted somewhere else. GLASS then syncs up(I think using GoogleCloudMessaging) with the hosted timeline and the items are then fetched and stored locally.

I'm not sure if this answers your question, however, I want to bring this thread back up. I was about to ask the same question regarding the hosting of the timeline items of both scenarios.